# Stronger conditions for proof of Implicit Function Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading a [proof of the IFT](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/280/multipliers.pdf):

- $F(x,y) = 0$
- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ defined and continuous in an open neighbourhood, $A$ of a point $(x_0, y_0)$
- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \ne 0$ in $A$
- $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0) > 0$

Then there exists a square in $A$, $S = \{ (x, y): |x-x_0| < k, |y-y_0|<k\}$ such that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} > 0$ on $S$

Does this not also require that $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y}$ be continuous on $A$?

Comment: No? It is just saying that there is a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\partial_yF>0$, which is a result of continuity of $\partial_yF$

Comment: @LiChunMin But, doesn't this only mean there is an interval $(y_0-k, y_0+k)$ with fixed $x_0$ such that $\partial_y F > 0$ ?

Comment: In $\Bbb{R}^2$, the open ball is a circle, so any rectangle inside that circle that contains $(x_0,y_0)$ is fine.

Comment: @LiChunMin Oh - nevermind. I see. $\partial_y F$ is still a function of both $x,y$, and so the condition that $\partial_y F$ is continuous is in the multivariable sense. My mistake. I will delete soon.

Comment: Well I don't know if you have to delete dat:P